# Is it possible to refer to a device by its alias in bluetoothctl

Tags: linux, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I have a device paired to my raspberry pi and configured the alias as 'cardreader'. This alters how I see it in scans so I see "cardreader" instead of its model number. So far so good. But now I would like to pair/trust/connect to that device using its alias rather than the macid/bluetooth card id. Something like `pair cardreader` instead of `pair 43:22:15:15:...`. The actual result of this is an error about not finding the device. I have found little documentation on bluez online and practically no talk about set-alias. If I can't do this I will resort to writing some commands to do this but it would be a shame since it seems like such an obvious feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems that `bluetoothctl` commands cannot operate on aliases. Even worse, `bluetoothctl` provides no specific command for getting the MAC Address of a device given its alias.

The best I could do is with the following:

```bash
ALIAS=<your-device-alias>
bluetoothctl connect `bluetoothctl devices | grep $ALIAS | cut -d ' ' -f 2`
```

The part:

```bash
bluetoothctl devices | grep $ALIAS | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

finds the MAC Address of a device given its alias name. The result is then used as the argument for `bluetoothctl connect`.

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple script that lets you connect to your paired devices using aliases.
Sadly it doesn't handle *pairing* itself -- mostly because I don't do it often so I haven't felt a need to implement it, feel free to add to this.

You can connect to any number of known devices using `bt device1 device2 device3` etc.

`bt`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# vi: ft=bash

mapfile deviceList < <(bluetoothctl -- devices)
length=$(echo -n "${deviceList[@]}" | wc -l)

declare -A devices
for (( i=0; i < $length; i++ )); do
    addr=$( echo ${deviceList[$i]} | cut -d " " -f 2 )
    name=$( echo ${deviceList[$i]} | cut -d " " -f 3-)
    devices["$name"]="$addr"
done

bluetoothctl -- power on && sleep 1 || exit 1

while [[ "$@" ]]; do
    bluetoothctl -- connect "${devices["$1"]}" || echo "Unrecognised device: $1"
    shift
    sleep 1
done
```

Be aware that since it builds the device list every time, it might be slow if you have a HUGE number of known devices.